# Assign NSDictionary to a global NSMUtableDictionary in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting a JSON `NSDictionary`in this way

```
guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
```

What I want to do now is, create an empty `NSMutableDictionary` in globally and assign this `json` to that global `NSMutableDictionary`. How can I do this in swift? Please help me.

Comment: Well, what do you have so far? It's hard to answer this without context.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: var mutableJson = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: json) should work. I'm not even sure that just "guard var json" could make the trick ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to have a global dictionary somewhere you can access. Some people put global things in the AppDelegate, but personally I don't like doing that so another solution you could do would be to create a Globals singleton class and allow that to store the new dictionary and any other globals you find you need throughout the project. That way you could just access the dictionary via the Globals class.

```
class Globals {
    static let sharedInstance = Globals()
    class var mySavedDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()

    private init() {
        //
    }
}
```

Then you could access the mySavedDictionary instance by something along these lines...

```
guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
    }

Globals.sharedInstance.mySavedDictionary = json
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a swift Dictionary for this.

```
guard let json : [String : AnyObject] = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String : AnyObject] else {throw JSONError.ConversionFailed}
if let string = json["key"] as? String {
print(string)
}
```

Or use a var if you want to mutate it.